# NodeJs PG query not executed as expected

Tags: javascript, node.js, postgresql, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda

I have the following, AWS lambda code inserting into a table:

```
let queryString = "INSERT INTO orders(order_id, channel, channel_order_id, channel_order_code, channel_merchant, merchant, min_time, max_time, delivery_expected_time, status, observations, total, sub_total, voucher_discount, delivery_tax, fk_customer_id, fk_address_id, order_contact, order_type, payment_pending, payment_prepaid, channel_merchant_id, order_timming, picker, delivered_by, delivery_obs, takeout, takeout_date_time, takeout_obs, indoor, table)VALUES($1, $2, $3, $4, $5, $6, $7, $8, $9, $10, $11, $12, $13, $14, $15, $16, $17, $18, $19, $20, $21, $22, $23, $24, $25, $26, $27, $28, $29, $30, $31) RETURNING *";

const newOrder = await client.query(queryString, [order_id, channel, channel_order_id, channel_order_code, channel_merchant, merchant, min_time, max_time, delivery_expected_time, status, observations, total, sub_total, voucher_discount, delivery_tax, fk_customer_id, fk_address_id, order_contact, order_type, payment_pending, payment_prepaid, channel_merchant_id, order_timming, picker, delivered_by, delivery_obs, takeout, takeout_date_time, takeout_obs, indoor, table], (err, res) => {
        if(err)console.log(res, err)
    });
```

And then another insert in a table that has a foreign key that references an `order(order_id)`, which should be the one being created at the first insert

I'm getting an error, on the second insert, that says that the `order(order_id)` does not exist. So it means that the order is not being created, the first insert is not being executed, but nothing is being caught in the `console.log(err)`

Now the interesting part. If I remove the `table` column from the first insert everything goes as expected

If I `console.log(table)` I get `null`
And the column is `NotNull = False`, which means that it can be null, just like as other values I'm using on the insert

Any hint on what could be happening here? Is there a limit of how many columns I can have on an insert?

Comment: `table` is a keyword. It should be `\`table\``.

Comment: Best way to troubleshoot these sort of issues is to `tail` the Postgres log file when you run the queries and see what is actually hitting the database and if there are error messages that are not being passed up the stack.

Comment: The error is probably swallowed because you are mixing awaiting the promise and using a callback. Wrap it in a try catch block and delete the callback. And yeah ... "table".

Comment: Also on a somewhat pendantic note: this is a monster of a table, mixing quite a few unrelated aspects of "an order" all into the same schema. Consider at least _some_ normalization, if only to make debugging bad queries a heck of a lot easier.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`table` is a [keyword in Postgres.](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/8.1/sql-keywords-appendix.html)

If you're insisting on continuing to maintain a column in your schema with the name `table` (not advisable), you'll need to pass it in quotes when referencing it:

```
INSERT INTO orders ("table") /* ... */
```